# parameter with value when assigned to a list item it becomes null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this method which passes in parameters and all the parameters hold a value but when i assign them to my viewModel one of them becomes null and not sure why:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(VisitViewModel viewModel, Guid[] associatedCasesSelected, Guid[] selectedParties)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.Time = _timeEntryHelper.Value;
            AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        var visitEntry = Mapper.Map<VisitViewModel, VisitEntry>(viewModel);
        visitEntry.VisitDate = _timeEntryHelper.AddTimeToDate(visitEntry.VisitDate);
        visitEntry.UserId = _currentUser.UserId;
        visitEntry.OfficeId = _currentUser.OfficeId;
        viewModel.AssociatedCasesSelected = associatedCasesSelected;
        viewModel.PartiesSelected = selectedParties;
        try
        {
            _visitEntryService.Create(visitEntry, associatedCasesSelected, selectedParties);
            this.FlashInfo(string.Format(Message.ConfirmationMessageCreate, Resources.Entities.Visit.EntityName));
        }
        catch (RulesException ex)
        {
            ex.CopyTo(ModelState);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Case", new { caseId = viewModel.CaseId });
        AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

This is the line:

```
viewModel.PartiesSelected = selectedParties;
```

selectedParties should hold one value but when i assign it to partiesSelected - it shows me while debugging that PartiesSelected = null;

This is partiesSelected in my viewModel:

```
public IList<Guid> PartiesSelected { get; set; }
```

Comment: you need to new up the list and then use the .Add() to populate it.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've shown us. You get `selectedParties` as a parameter and you never touch it until the problem happens. Debug line by line and find out when it turns null.

Comment: @YoryeNathan when i debug i hover over the selectedParties in the paramter and find that it is: System.Guid[1]. As i debug associated cases are assigned fine but when i hit partiesSelected it is null.